# How many combinations are there in RGB without editing blue component values?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, rgb, visual-web-developer

If the blue part of a RGB value were set to 0, how many color combinations do I still have available by changing the other components values of the RGB value?

Comment: 256*256*1 .......

Answer (score 2):

RGB usually allows a value between 0 and 255 for each colour.

Normally, that means 256<sup>3</sup> = 16,777,216 or about 16.8 million colour combinations.

Setting Blue to zero gives you no choice there, so the combinations become 256<sup>2</sup> = 65,536 or **about 65 and a half thousand colour combination.**

Comment: It's actually 256³ and 256², value between 0 and 255 has 256 possible options.

Comment: Oof you're right. Missed that. Updated the answer but not sure it's even necessary to at this point

Comment: Colour is spelled color not that is matters anymore.

Comment: @JaimeArgila spelling depends on where you live. USA uses "color", but most of the rest of the English-speaking world uses "colour".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is 256² = 65536 squared instead of cubed because you eliminated the blue color.